# Run Xamarin.iOS app in real device

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use an iPhone 6 for running Xamarin.iOS app.
I connect iPhone to my Mac(in VMware), and not Windows Machine When I select iPhone in VS 2015 menu my iPhone name appear on VS 2015.
[image]
However , always show loading in Main.storyboard and doesn't show design and when I run the project I get this error : 
Error : MessagingRemoteException: An error occured on client Build42217 executing a reply for topic xvs/Build/4.2.2.11/execute-
task/Lesson1/7b0d249%FDetectSigningldentiy
DirectoryNotFounfException: Directory '/Users/arazpashazadeh/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles' not found.

What solution would you recommend to solve this problem?

Comment: did you create a development provisioning profile for your device?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do when i want to build on my Iphone

To deploy on your device, you need :

- A Macintosh
- Connect visual studio with MacAgent to your Macintosh
- Create X-Code project to create a Bundle identifier
- Plug your device on your mac
- Build it on your device

Don't forget to authorize your app in (settings -> General -> Profils -> Dev App )
In xCode project in info.plist copy Bundle indentifier and paste it in your VS info.plist

Hope this helps you

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1) If you haven't created a development provisioning profile for your device, follow this manual:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/

2) If you had created the profile before, open Xcode, click `Xcode` in the top left corner of the screen, click `Preferences`, click `Accounts`, sign in if needed, click `View Details` and click `Download All Profiles`.

3) Consider restarting the Visual Studio to synchronize.

Also make sure that your profiles are not expired.

You can also check the `'/Users/arazpashazadeh/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles'` directory:
Inside VMWare, click Shift+Win+G, type `~/Library` and navigate to `Mobile Device` folder. If you see `Provisioning Profiles` folder in there but it still doesn't work, you can try to move it to trash and repeat step #2 and #3.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your guidance but when I log on to the Developer Center to accept license show me : To continue your enrollment, complete your purchase now and redirect me to Purchase Details page to pay US$ 99 cost for 1 year , but in the above link not to pay cost.
then I try generate a development certificate manually again redirect to Purchase Details page to pay US$ 99 cost for 1 year.
Why this happened to me؟

I try second step and add my Apple ID but in the View Details I don't have profiles for download

[image]

why created a development step different for me?